# Missing sqli for phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm currently meeting an issue with `phpmyadmin`.
I install everything as the Arch wiki said.

```
php version : 7.1.13
php71-mcrypt
```

I have this when I tried to get to `phpmyadmin` :

[image]

I already uncommented those 2 extensions:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=mysqli.so
```

Why am I having this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you restart httpd server?

Comment: yes I did it and nothing change

Comment: If you running on localhost cold you check if you put `mysqli.allow_local_infile = On` in php.ini file and restarting would help? And what says [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) - is mysqli module loaded?

Comment: Here is what I have in phpinfo();
https://ibb.co/dyUrvc

Comment: I suppose it is loaded.

Comment: this is how php is compiled, there should be a section `mysqli`

Comment: I redo the installation of Lamp and PMA, and somehow when I got to localhost/phpmyadmin.

it display the source code instead of the page.